# Replace a JSON property dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to replace "placeholder" with {"John": "Dough"} dynamically with a function call.

This works:

```
a = {foo:{bar:{baz:"placeholder"}}};
a.foo.bar.baz = {"John" : "Dough"};
console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); 

> {"foo":{"bar":{"baz":{"John":"Dough"}}}}
```

But this doesn't:

```
var test = function(key, value) {
    a = {foo:{bar:{baz:"placeholder"}}};
    a.foo.bar.baz = { key: value};
    console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
    };
test("John", "Dough");

> {"foo":{"bar":{"baz":{"key":"Dough"}}}}
```

This also doesn't work:

```
var test = function(key, value) {
    a = {foo:{bar:{baz:"placeholder"}}};
    a.foo.bar.baz[key] = value;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
    };
test("John", "Dough");

> {"foo":{"bar":{"baz":"placeholder"}}}
```

I am testing on Node.js. Probably won't change in browser.

Comment: there is no such thing "json object" in java script. there's json, which is the serielized form of an object, and an object. period. saying json object it's like saying "cake-recipe cake", either it's a recipe cake, either it's a cake. there's no between.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - This question is not answered by the one you refer to as a duplicate.  This question is asking how to replace a property.  If you actually look at the code supplied then you can see that the OP already knows how to dynamically refer to properties using variables as key names.  He does it.  Stop before you mark as duplicate in future.

Comment: @DavidHaim I corrected the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function as bellow

```
var test = function(key, value) {
    a = {foo:{bar:{baz:"placeholder"}}};
    a.foo.bar.baz = {};   //creating a new object as `baz` value then assign
    a.foo.bar.baz[key] = value;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
};
```

Comment: Devil's advocate here - what if `baz` is not the only property of `bar`?  With this code you'll wipe out all other properties.

Comment: nope I'm just saying `bar.baz={}`, why this will affect other properties of `bar `?

Comment: @Archer nope, if you see the `this works` part, it has `{"foo":{"bar":{"baz":{"John":"Dough"}}}}` as expected.

Comment: Sod it - Sorry.  I need my morning coffee :p